# Change one of many toggle button label with same function - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have a bunch of `paper-toggle-buttons` that I am wanting to have the label display its current state.

I can get this to work simply enough on one button, but I am wanting to have them point to one function so that my code is cleaner.

I currently have this code, however both will toggle at the same time???
It's definitely the JS that is wrong.

[image]

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'example-element',
  properties: {
    labelText: {
      type: String,
      value: 'false'
    }
  },
  checkToggle: function(e) {
    var toggleButton = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('input');
    this.$$('#' + toggleButton).checked ? this.labelText = "True" : this.labelText = "False";
  },
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+polymer+v1.9.0/components/" />
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html" />

<example-element></example-element>

<dom-module id="example-element">
  <template>
    <paper-toggle-button input="paper-toggle1" id="paper-toggle1" on-click="checkToggle">{{labelText}}</paper-toggle-button>
    <paper-toggle-button input="paper-toggle2" id="paper-toggle2" on-click="checkToggle">{{labelText}}</paper-toggle-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: the problem is that you are changing this.labelText which will affect both I guess... You could maybe add another property to store the name of the variable to change? That seems over complicated for just a toggle tough. Are you sure it is getting cleaner??

Comment: Both of the toggle buttons are changed also however.

I will add a gif to my question to demonstrate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger an event when one of a set of Polymer paper-toggle-buttons is pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682028/trigger-an-event-when-one-of-a-set-of-polymer-paper-toggle-buttons-is-pushed)

Comment: This question looks exactly the same as the one you posted a year and a half ago. The exact same solution can apply.

Comment: I still can't get the answer, even looking at previous posts etc. Any help rather than just shouting at me?

Comment: Please add more code then... Where does {{toggle}} come from? Show us enough code so we can actually reproduce what is currently happening.

Comment: Edited - Turns out the {{toggled}} wasn't needed. Was just what was on the code I was going off of. Now both aren't toggled but the text still changes.

Comment: Use 2 variables instead of one...

Comment: You mean like using {{labelText1}} and {{LabelText2}}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No point using a custom property for this, you may as well change the dom directly. This is just one way of doing it.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'example-element',
  properties: {
    labelText: {
      type: String,
      value: 'false'
    }
  },
  checkToggle: function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.querySelector(".label").innerHTML = e.currentTarget.checked == true;
  },
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+polymer+v1.9.0/components/" />
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html" />

<example-element></example-element>

<dom-module id="example-element">
  <template>
    <paper-toggle-button input="paper-toggle1" id="paper-toggle1" on-click="checkToggle"><span class="label">false</span></paper-toggle-button>
    <paper-toggle-button input="paper-toggle2" id="paper-toggle2" on-click="checkToggle"><span class="label">false</span></paper-toggle-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I knew it was something along these lines. Thanks Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing only the innerText of the toggle which was clicked:

```
checkToggle : function(e) {
    var toggleButton = this.$$('#' + e.currentTarget.getAttribute('input'));
    toggleButton.checked ? toggleButton.innerText = "True" : toggleButton.innerText = "False";
}
```

Comment: Hey Pascal, the label doesn't change when using your code :-(

Comment: Dammit was just a guess :-/

Answer (score 0):

Use the strength of properties.

```
 <paper-toggle-button checked="{{paperToggle1}}">[[paperToggle1]]</paper-toggle-button>
 <paper-toggle-button checked="{{paperToggle2}}">[[paperToggle2]]</paper-toggle-button>
```

You could do more advanced stuff as well, like saving each toggle button in an Object (`paperToggle.first`) nor adding a method that takes in the id and use that as a key in said Object.

Comment: Hey Rickard, this is what I originally had but I was binding to JSON properties meaning that I can't change the binding.